# Excel parse address character limit

Tags: excel, parsing, excel-formula, limit, maxlength

I am currently in the process of parsing adresses. The only requirement I have is that there should not be more than 40 characters in each Address cell (Address 1, Address 2, Address 3 etc). The problem is that the addresses all have different formats and I want to prevent words from being cut in the middle. Example for an address (in G column):
Naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaame, 342 Streeeeeet, city, 452342 Zip code, Country
That´s how far I got:

```
Adress3=IF(LEN(G3)>40;RIGHT(G3;LEN(G3)-FIND("*";SUBSTITUTE(G3;" ";"*";LEN(G3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(G3;" ";"")))));"")

Adress1==IF(I3<>""; IF(RIGHT(IF(I3<>"";TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(G3; I3; "")); G3);1)=",";LEFT(IF(I3<>"";TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(G3; I3; "")); G3);LEN(IF(I3<>"";TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(G3; I3; "")); G3))-1);IF(I3<>"";TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(G3; I3; "")); G3)); IF(I3<>"";TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(G3; I3; "")); G3))
```

This works, however I need to find a way to perform this operation multiple times (since some addresses are really long) so that I get something like:

Address1: 40 characters

Address2: 40 characters

Address3: remaining characters

Is there any way to solve this without using VBA?
I hope I am making sense and would appreciate any advice!!

Comment: Can you show an example of the input and output you want? Not clear if all your addresses are in one cell?

Comment: All the adresses have seperate cells in one column (G).
input: Naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaame, 342 Streeeeeet, city, 452342 Zip code, Country

Comment: Output: Address1: Naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaame, 342
Address2: Streeeeeet, city, 452342 Zip code,
Address3: Country
There should not be more than 40 characters in each address cell
Thanks for your help!

Comment: If I keep using the formula
=IF(LEN(G3)>40;RIGHT(G3;LEN(G3)-FIND("*";SUBSTITUTE(G3;" ";"*";LEN(G3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(G3;" ";"")))));"")
I end up with one word per cell which does not make a lot of sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These three progressive formula seem to work for your single example.

[image: Parse and Truncate Address with worksheet functions]

The formulas in G5:K5 are:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(G3, " ", REPT(" ", 99), 40-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(G3, 40), " ", ""))), 40))
=IFERROR(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(G3, LEN(G5&REPT(" ", 1)), 40), " ", REPT(" ", 99), 40-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(MID(G3, LEN(G5&REPT(" ", 1)), 40), 40), " ", ""))), 40)), "")
=IFERROR(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(G3, LEN(G5&H5&REPT(" ", 2)), 40), " ", REPT(" ", 99), 40-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(MID(G3, LEN(G5&H5&REPT(" ", 2)), 40), 40), " ", ""))), 40)), "")
=IFERROR(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(G3, LEN(G5&H5&I5&REPT(" ", 3)), 40), " ", REPT(" ", 99), 40-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(MID(G3, LEN(G5&H5&I5&REPT(" ", 3)), 40), 40), " ", ""))), 40)), "")
=IFERROR(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(G3, LEN(G5&H5&I5&J5&REPT(" ", 4)), 40), " ", REPT(" ", 99), 40-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(MID(G3, LEN(G5&H5&I5&J5&REPT(" ", 4)), 40), 40), " ", ""))), 40)), "")
```

Note that the formula in H5 is dependent on the result in G5 and the formula in I5 is dependent on the results in H5 and G5.

Not sure what you might want to do with the trailing comma in H5.

Comment: The formula works wonderfully if the address isn´t longer than 120 characters. How can I find a formula Address4 (Address5) for the remaining characters (that are now simply cut off)?

Comment: The next one would use `MID(G3, LEN(G5&"   "&H5&I5), 40)` and the next one would use `MID(G3, LEN(G5&"    "&H5&I5&J5), 40)` (in two places each). Each one starts at a position equal to the length of all previous pieces plus a space for each piece.

Comment: OK, makes a lot of sense! Thanks again for your time!